# chrome doesn't load images

Tags: google-chrome, joomla

I am using Joomla 2.5 and I have been trying to load a bunch of images in a page. They load just fine in FF/Safari but don't load in chrome.

Originally my code is something like this:

```
<div id="sponsors">
    <img src ="<?php echo $apath; ?>/images/ads/ad__03.png" />
    <img src ="<?php echo $apath; ?>/images/ads/ad2.png" />
    <img src ="<?php echo $apath; ?>/images/ads/ad3.png" />
    <img src ="<?php echo $apath; ?>/images/ads/ad4.png" />
    <img src ="<?php echo $apath; ?>/images/ads/ad5.png" />
    <img src ="<?php echo $apath; ?>/images/ads/ad6.png" />
    <img src ="<?php echo $apath; ?>/images/ads/ad7.png" />
</div>
```

which is rendered as:
[image]

in chrome.

I also checked the network tab in dev tools. There are two attempts made for the images to load:
[image]
[image]

The template works perfectly in other browsers. I have tried moving the images into other folders, but chrome just refuses to show the images.

Comment: Use full paths, not sure that's the problem but it's better if you do.

Comment: @elclanrs problem persists.

Comment: it's not because of path, but because of styles. chrome won't load images which are set not to be displayed. question is why are they set to `display: none` etc

Comment: or `visibility: hidden` at the same time.  Two very different effects.

Comment: Yeah but that's not my style attributes. Chrome forcibly add these attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have some ad blocking plugin (AdBlockPlus)? This will occur also on FF with similar plugins.

The issue is that you have the word **ads** in your images' urls.

The only solution I could find was to rename the "ads" part of the url, from what you write it seems like it shouldn't be hard.